# PHP create nested array and pass back with json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have the following, and while `$data['details']` is being populated OK, there should be three results in `$data['tests']`, but "tests" isn't showing at all in the JSON result:

{"details":["Clinical result","Signature result"]}

```
$data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$data['details'] = array($row['tests_clinical'], $row['signature']);
foreach($row['lab_test_group_fk'] as $group){
$data['tests'] = array($group);
}
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

If I change the above to the following then I get only the last record for `$row['lab_test_group_fk']`, not all three records for that column (hence the foreach loop as above):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$data['details'] = array($row['tests_clinical'], $row['signature']);
$data['tests'] = array($row['lab_test_group_fk']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

{"details":["Clinical result","Signature result"],"tests":["21"]}

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks to Tamil Selvin this was the solution that worked for me:

```
$data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$data['details'] = array($row['tests_clinical'], $row['signature']);
$data['tests'][] = array($row['lab_test_group_fk']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Which returned:

{"details":["Clinical result","Signature result"],"tests":[["31"],["2"],["21"]]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $data[]['details'] = array($row['tests_clinical'], $row['signature']);
  $data[]['tests'] = array($row['lab_test_group_fk']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

or

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$data[] = array(
     'details' => array($row['tests_clinical'], $row['signature']),
      'tests' => array($row['lab_test_group_fk'])
);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: @Taiml..  closer, that gives me {"details":[["Clinical result","Signature result"],["Clinical result","Signature result"],["Clinical result","Signature result"]],"tests":[["31"],["2"],["21"]]}

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 what your expected result

Comment: tests_clinical and signature should be one record for each whilst lab_test_group_fk can be many.  So changing $data[]['details'] to just $data['details'] works fine..and keeping $data[]['tests'] as is.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`$data['tests'] = array($group);` means reassign `$data['tests']` to a new value again.

Try `$data['tests'][] = array($group);` .

Comment: @zairwolf...That still returns just {"details":["Clinical result","Signature result"]}

Comment: I just tell you how to do, not what to do. Use `$data['details'][] = array($row['tests_clinical'], $row['signature']);` too.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting existing data of $data. You need some kind of array where you will put all your records. Try this

```
$data = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $record = array();   // this creates new record
    $record['details'] = array($row['tests_clinical'], $row['signature']);
    foreach($row['lab_test_group_fk'] as $group){
         $record['tests'] = array($group);
    }
    $data[] = $record;     // this adds record to data
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: that returns [{"details":["Clinical result","Signature result"]},{"details":["Clinical result","Signature result"]},{"details":["Clinical result","Signature result"]}]